# Postgres split LineStrings and convert

Tags: postgresql, split, postgis, plpgsql

my question is how to build a function in PL/pgSQL to do this :

i have many linestrings like this.

```
Linestring((3.584731 60.739211,3.590472 60.738030,3.592740 60.736220))
```

I need to split every Linestring in a Substring and split it up again in 2 coordinates like this.

```
3.584731 60.739211  
x1            y1      

3.590472 60.738030 
x2            y2     


3.592740 60.736220
x3              y3
```

And so on with the other points. 
Save the answers and converting into a double so I can calculate with the points.

Comment: Your title says `PL/SQL` - which would indicate Oracle. But in the question you say `PL/pgSQL` which would be Postgres. Which DBMS are you using? Oracle or Postgres?

Comment: sorry i need this in PL/pgSQL and i use postgreSQL :). Im using pgAdmin III

Comment: My problem is that i never build functions with in PL/pgSQL and i need this really necessary for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) like this:

```
SELECT ST_X(d.geom), ST_Y(d.geom)
FROM ST_DumpPoints(
    'Linestring(3.584731 60.739211,3.590472 60.738030,3.592740 60.736220)') AS d;

   st_x   |   st_y    
----------+-----------
 3.584731 | 60.739211
 3.590472 |  60.73803
  3.59274 |  60.73622
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks :) Now i need a pl/pgSQL-function who do this part and get the result like you have done this and calculate with the numbers like f((3.584731)²+(60.739211)²)+  ((3.590472)²+(60.73803)²) +  ((3.59274)²+(60.73622)²) and get the result in a row. This would save my life :)

Comment: I know it doesnt make sense but its a testfunction for a project

Comment: @sataide: so you just changed your question. Mike's statement *does* answer the question "how to split this up". Please don't extend the question with new problems after one problem is solved.

Comment: Ok  i will do this :)