# Convert linestring to array of points?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have postgres with postgis and i need to convert linestring to array of points

i already examined with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035149/postgres-split-linestrings-and-convert), my question is similar, but also i need to aggregate it to array

from this

```
Linestring((3.584731 60.739211,3.590472 60.738030,3.592740 60.736220))
```

to this

```
["3.584731 60.739211","3.590472 60.738030","3.592740 60.736220"]
```

how can i do that?

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: i have select `WITH rstemp as (SELECT st_dumppoints(st_astext(path)) AS path, id FROM route_sequence)
SELECT
  rcc.order,
  rcc.checkpoint_id,
  rcc.route_id,
  rcc.is_forward,
  array_agg(st_x(rstemp.path.geom))
FROM route_cached_checkpoint AS rcc
  JOIN route_sequence AS rs ON rs.id = ANY (rcc.next_rsq)
  JOIN rstemp ON rstemp.id = rs.id
WHERE rcc.date = (DATE '2016-04-27');`

Comment: I suggest you [create a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html) to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know why you would need this but here you go:

```
WITH
    route_sequence AS (
      SELECT id, path
      FROM (
        VALUES
          (1, 'Linestring(3.584731 60.739211,3.590472 60.738030,3.592740 60.736220)'),
          (2, 'Linestring(3.584731 60.739211,3.590472 60.738030,3.592740 60.736220)')
      ) AS route_sequence(id, path)
  ),
  rstemp AS (
      SELECT
        route_sequence.id,
        array_agg(
            ST_X(points.geom)::CHARACTER VARYING
            || ' '
            || ST_Y(points.geom)::CHARACTER VARYING
            ORDER BY points.path[1] ASC
        ) AS coordinates
      FROM route_sequence, ST_DumpPoints(path) as points(path, geom)
      GROUP BY route_sequence.id
  )
SELECT *
FROM rstemp
;
```

I am very curious to know why you would need an array here. Maybe there is another way. Why can't you keep the initial `geom` generated by `ST_DumpPoints` ?

Comment: yesterday at midnight i already create select that i need, anyway thanks for your answer(i will try it, maybe it will work faster)

for what i need array? this will be serializing to json by python for api, from this json two mobile apps(ios and android) will be creating polylines on map, so that's it

i will post now my example

P.S. sorry for my english

Comment: Ok that make sense then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH points_text AS (SELECT
                   (st_dumppoints(path)).geom AS points,
                   (st_dumppoints(path)).path AS points_path,
                   rs.id,
                   rcc.checkpoint_id,
                   rcc.route_id,
                   rcc."order",
                   rcc.is_forward,
                   rcc.is_primary
                 FROM route_cacheed_checkpoint AS rcc
                   JOIN route_sequence AS rs ON rs.id = ANY (rcc.next_rsq)
                 WHERE rcc.date = (DATE '2016-04-28') AND rcc.is_primary = TRUE)
SELECT
    array_agg(to_char(ST_X(points), 'FM99.9999990') || to_char(ST_Y(points), '99.9999990') ORDER BY points_path) AS path,
    pt.checkpoint_id,
    pt.route_id,
    pt."order",
    pt.is_forward                 AS is_forward_direction,
    pt.is_primary
FROM points_text AS pt
GROUP BY pt.id, pt.checkpoint_id, pt.route_id, pt."order", pt.is_forward, pt.is_primary
ORDER BY pt.is_forward DESC, pt."order";
```